# Crypted Gobbledygook, Decrypted Obvious

Tags: cipher

#### When it is crypted, it is gobbledygook, when it is decrypted everyone who reads it here understands!

> zorrqpxj gzu
> fuebmtvbkexjt gzu
> baq

Happing decoding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's a substitution cipher with a plaintext we all know, and there's a repeated three letter word.. I'll go with

> puzzling.stackexchange.com

Comment: That's it but just to be sure, how would you crypt Bass?

Comment: I’m not a cipher-friendly person, could you explain what this means or give me a link to something I can read about?

Comment: @JKHA no idea whatsoever, the word lengths seemed to match, and there didn't seem to be any inconsistencies within the words, so I posted the answer. :-) Looks like there's something tricky going on with the dots though..

Comment: @Bass, then I'm upvoting your answer but can't accept it yet :)

Comment: Is it good enough for the tick if I tell you that the first and the last letters are inconsistent in the ciphertext? :-)

Comment: @Bass, haha! Let's explain it well in your answer for other people reading it and I'll tick it :)

Comment: @JKHA I give up, almost every letter matches the pattern (several multiply repeated ones included), so trying to figure out some other pattern from exactly two differing data points seems hopeless.